# What happens when I submit 2 requests to the same URL?

Tags: java, multithreading, http, browser

I have a Java web application, sitting in a Jetty container. I would like to know what happens if I submit 2 requests to the same URL one immediately after the other. Assume that the requests are simple GET requests and have no side effects.

I imagine what happens for each request is that a HTTP request is made to the URL, Jetty receives it and starts up a new thread to handle the request, then generates the response and sends it back over HTTP.

In the context of a browser - if I have sent off a second request before the first one returns, does the first response simply get discarded and not used? Is it effectively a wasted transaction?

Comment: Why you just don't try it...?

Comment: Well, since each request is being served by its own thread, why should the second kill the first?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you have no way of knowing that the server isn't providing a different response to each get -- perhaps incrementing a hit counter, as one trivial example -- so unless the server, or your client, is explicitly set up to cache results each request gets processed independently.

Comment: But what if I'm in my browser window and I fire off the request, then fire off a second one? Which response is rendered in the browser?

Comment: In the same window and tab? Usually the browser discards the first session and displays the second, if there's time to do so. If not, the browser displays, then redisplays. But that's details of browser implementation, not HTTP communications.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I guess my question should be clearer. I'll edit it.